# Can a conductor's empty cavity contain an electric field?

Tags: electrostatics

Assume there is no external field. Is it possible to have an electrically neutral conductor with a cavity such that an electric field in the cavity is sustainable at electrostatic equilibrium?

Here is the cross section of an attempt.

[image: attempt at a conductor cavity with sustainable equilibrium field]

Here, the charges in the two central dongles are attracted to each other and generate an electric field, but cannot move because of the geometry. This attempt actually does not work, because there will actually be an electric field induced along the vertical walls of the cavity, causing current to flow which neutralizes the field.

However, it's hard to prove that there is *no* shape that can work. Is there such a proof?

Comment: As for real materials, are you thinking of something like semiconductors? I'm actually remembering just now that there is a stable electric field inside a p-n junction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @BrunoAnghioni for the reference. I will restate the argument given.

If such a configuration were possible, one could create a closed line integral that had a positive integral $\oint E \cdot dl \gt 0$. But electric fields are conservative.

Here is the relevant figure from **Introduction to Electrodynamics** by Griffiths.

[image: contradictory line integral]

A nonzero electric field is equivalent to the existence of a path such that $\oint E \cdot dl \gt 0$

For the path, we may simply find a flow line of the field $E$ by solving $\gamma'(t) = E(\gamma(t))$, starting a point inside the cavity where the field is not zero. The only bad thing that could happen is that our flow line terminates inside the interior of the cavity and does not connect up with any flow line that leads out of the cavity. But then we would have a net flux inwards around that point, and by Gauss' law, there would be a charge there. This contradicts the fact that the cavity is empty. So the flow line enters and exits the cavity. To close the path, we can then connect the endpoints through the conductor.